# [RDO]OpenStack構築後のインスタンス起動失敗について

Tags: centos

CentOS7 + Juno をpackstackでインストールを行いました。
構成は、コントローラーノード(neutronを含む)1台、コンピュートノード2台で行っています。
はじめにコントローラーノード台 + コンピュートノード1台の構成で行ったところ、
インストールから、インスタンスの起動、FloatingIPの割り当てまですべてうまくいきました。

続いて、コンピュートノードを一台増設しようと思い、
answerファイルの`CONFIG_COMPUTE_HOSTS`にIPアドレスを設定し、
すでに構築済みの一台につきましては、`EXCLUDE_SERVERS`へ退避を致しました。

この状態で、`packstack`コマンドを実行し、インストールもうまくいったのですが、
インスタンスの起動ができなくなってしまいました。

コントローラー、コンピュートノードでログを確認すると、

```
NovaException: Unexpected vif_type=binding_failed
```

というエラーメッセージが各コンピュートノードで返ってきており起動にしているみたいです。

お忙しいところ申し訳ございませんが、
もし、お時間があればご教授頂ければ幸いです。

#### 追記

$ neutron agent-list -F host -F agent_type
  +--------------------+--------------------------+
| agent_type         | host                     |
+--------------------+--------------------------+
| Open vSwitch agent | openstack.controller |
| L3 agent           | openstack.controller |
| Open vSwitch agent | openstack.compute001 |
| DHCP agent         | openstack.controller |
| Metadata agent     | openstack.controller |
  +--------------------+--------------------------+

computeノードがもう一台稼働しているはずなのですが、
ここに出てこないのはおかしいですか?

### 追記

Open vSwitch agentはコンピュートノードにおいて動作しておりましたが、
agent-listでは表示されていません。
動作はしているが、コントローラーが知らないという状況なのでしょうか....

### 追記

現状の設定ファイルです。

https://gist.github.com/tomomura/39a006413c6b390aefdd#file-gistfile2-txt

Comment: 回答はできないのですが：OpenStack関連のトラブルは環境構成に強く依存するケースが多いので、自分でログファイルとにらめっこしないとなかなか解決しづらい気がします。[ask.openstack.org](https://ask.openstack.org/en/questions/query:NovaException%3A%20Unexpected%20vif_type%3Dbinding_failed/)でも類似ケースがいくつか質問されているようです。運が良ければ参考になるかもしれません。（Neutron側の問題かも？？）

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。環境構築はかなりログとにらめっこして、コントローラー１、コンピュート１の構成はできたので、１台増やしただけで、インスタンスが起動できないのがなかなか納得できず、苦戦しております。

Comment: packstackは使った事無いので分からないのですが、[Adding a compute node](https://openstack.redhat.com/Adding_a_compute_node)あたりが参考になるんでしょうか。`vif_type`だとインスタンスに接続される仮想ネットワークポート設定関連だと思うので、NovaとNeutronをセットで見ていった方がよいかもしれませんね。

Comment: はい、この通りにまず1台コンピュートを追加・成功し、2台目の追加を実行したところで、現状です。

Comment: 改めて調べると、最初の一回目(CirrOS)は起動することがわかりました。
しかし、2台以上のインスタンスを起動しようとすると、同じエラーで失敗してしまいます。

Comment: 補足ですが、同じイメージからCirrOSを2つ起動しようとしています。

Comment: 追記分は`neutron agent-list`の実行結果ですか？コンピュートノードでは、セットで"Open vSwitch agent"(Neutron L2 agent)が稼働している必要があります。ちなみにオプション`-F host -F agent_type`をつけると出力がみやすくなります。

Comment: そうです。ご教授ありがとうございます。再度実行して編集しました。
なるほど、ということはもう一つの新規追加分のComputeノードでOpen vSwitch agentが動作していないのが、今回の問題に関係してる可能性があるということでしょうか?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己解決できました。

原因は、サーバ間の時間の同期ができていなかった為です。

NTPサーバを用意して、各サーバ間の時間を同期させたところ正常に動作しました。

ありがとうございました。

Comment: たしかにOpenStackでは[NTPによるサーバ間時刻同期](http://docs.openstack.org/ja/trunk/install-guide/install/apt/content/basics-ntp.html)を要求していますね。（このような形でエラーになるとは…）